# Visual Studio 2010 on Team Build server?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfsbuild

Do I need to install Visual Studio 2010 on my TFS 2010 Build server, if I want to run Unit Tests and Coded UI Tests as part of my build process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you do not need  it IF you do not need them. But...

Still do it ;) There is a lot of third party stuff that may rely on Visual Studio to exist. On top, some of the Visual studio PROJECT TYPES are not supported WITHOUT Visual Studio (like database projects).

I am not sure about unit testing and coded UI tests.... I think those are part of the visual studio setup, so you have to actually install it to have them available.

Comment: Unit tests are supported in the TFS Build Service installation, but coded UI tests are not. For those you have two options, install VS on the build machine and re-configure the build service to run interactively (since those tests require an interactive desktop) or, run those tests in the context of "load tests" on a remote test agent.